# Matching SAS character variables to a list

Tags: sas, macros, sas-macro

So I have a vector of search terms, and my main data set. My goal is to create an indicator for each observation in my main data set where variable1 includes at least one of the search terms. Both the search terms and variable1 are character variables.

Currently, I am trying to use a macro to iterate through the search terms, and for each search term, indicate if it is in the variable1. I do not care which search term triggered the match, I just care that there was a match (hence I only need 1 indicator variable at the end).

I am a novice when it comes to using SAS macros and loops, but have tried searching and piecing together code from some online sites, unfortunately, when I run it, it does nothing, not even give me an error.

I have put the code I am trying to run below.

```
    *for example, I am just testing on one of the SASHELP data sets;
    *I take the first five team names to create a search list;
    data terms; set sashelp.baseball (obs=5);
    search_term = substr(team,1,3);
    keep search_term;;
    run;
    
    *I will be searching through the baseball data set;
    data test; set sashelp.baseball;
    run;
    
    
    %macro search;
    %local i name_list next_name;

    proc SQL;
    select distinct search_term into : name_list separated by ' ' from work.terms;
    quit;

    %let i=1;
    %do %while (%scan(&name_list, &i) ne );
    %let next_name = %scan(&name_list, &i);
    
    *I think one of my issues is here. I try to loop through the list, and use the find command to find the next_name and if it is in the variable, then I should get a non-zero value returned;
    data test; set test;
    indicator = index(team,&next_name);
    run;
    %let i = %eval(&i + 1);
    %end;
    %mend;
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use a macro? A temporary array would be more efficient IMO.

Comment: Are you searching through a specific field or looking for an exact match? If it's an exact match why not use a subquery?

Comment: I am searching through a specific field. So if my search term was "Bay", I would want to include "Green Bay Packers" and "Old Bay Seasoning" and "Bayleaf" in my matches. I don't need to use a macro, but I have not used subqueries really either.

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/How-to-delete-observation-with-specific-character-and-know-where/m-p/712572

Comment: Paste your terms from the macro variable into your temporary array from the solution in the link above.

Comment: I suppose that looks like it could work, although I will have to look for how to create an array from a data set. My list of search terms may end up being in the thousands and may change as I work through the project, so I don't exactly want to manually hard-code everything, hence the macro approach I tried. Thanks

Comment: You already created the macro variable with the list of terms and you can also populate an array from a data set.

Comment: I may be missing something, but when I try to use the macro variable that I have with the list of terms it shoots out an error because the terms are not quoted strings.

I also can't find anything on bringing in a separate data set as an array list online. I can find help on using variables from the data set I am using to fill an array, but in this case my list is observations in a separate data set, not variables in the data set I am trying to manipulate

Comment: What is you dataset sizes?  Did you try a simple SQL join to test every search term against every source string and then aggregate to the overall answer for the source string?   The MAX() of a series of boolean expressions is TRUE if ANY of them is TRUE.

Comment: My search terms will probably end up being around 1000 terms, and the data in my data set will likely be around 2 million observations, so a full join will almost surely crash my computer

Comment: Use the QUOTE() function to add quotes to the values in the SQL query to get a quoted list back. Your macro code must generate correct SAS code and not having the quotes is invalid.

Comment: How many "words" appear in your dataset variable that you want to search for the 1000 search terms, on average?  Is this a variable with 5-10 words in it? Or is it paragraphs of text?

Comment: And to be clear, I assume you are looking for "words" - if that's incorrect and you're looking for string bits that might not be words, that's a fine answer also (how long each one is in characters on average).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the temporary array solution which is fully data driven.

1. Store the number of terms in a macro variable to assign the length of arrays
2. Load terms to search into a temporary array
3. Loop through for each word and search the terms
4. Exit loop if you find the term to help speed up the process

```
/*1*/
proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into :num_search_terms from terms;
quit;

%put &num_search_terms.;



data flagged;

*declare array;
array _search(&num_search_terms.) $ _temporary_;

/*2*/
*load array into memory;
   if _n_ = 1 then do j=1 to &num_search_terms.;
   set terms;
   _search(j) = search_term;
   end;
 
 set test;
 
 *set flag to 0 for initial start;
 flag = 0;

/*3*/
*loop through and craete flag;
do i=1 to &num_search_terms. while(flag=0); /*4*/
   if find(team, _search(i), 'it')>0 then flag=1;
end;

drop i j search_term ;

run;
```

Comment: I think this is likely the best "easy" solution.  There're some more interesting ways to solve this depending on how the data are structured, and in particular if it's words and not any arbitrary character, or if the lengths are pretty short, but for general case this is not bad - on data of similar shape to what OP described, it ran in about a minute for search terms 5 long total data variable 30 long on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I totally understand what you are trying to do but if you want to add a new binary variable that indicates if any of the substrings are found just use code like:

```
data want;
  set have;
  indicator = index(term,'string1') or index(term,'string2') 
       ... or index(term,'string27')  ;
run;
```

Not sure what a "vector" would be but if you had the list of terms in a dataset you could easily generate that code from the data. And then use `%include` to add it to your program.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set term_list end=eof;
  file code ;
  if _n_ =1 then put 'indicator=' @ ;
  else put ' or ' @;
  put 'index(term,' string :$quote. ')' @;
  if eof then put ';' ;
run;
   
data want;
  set have;
%include code / source2;
run;
```

If you did want to think about creating a macro to generate code like that then the parameters to the macro might be the two input dataset names, the two input variable names and the output variable name.

Comment: I could use your first code, but I may end up with over a thousand different strings to search, so hard-coding all of those will take forever, and when I ultimately need to change them, it will be a huge hassle.

I will also be honest, I have no clue what is going on in your second code block.

Comment: Of course you don't want to type the statement, although it is not really any harder than managing the list of terms in some other way.  Do you have the list of substrings in a dataset or not? The second block is just generating the series of INDEX() function calls by writing the code to a file using normal SAS code for writing text to files.